Autodesk Forge Viewer - set orbit "not free"
is it possible to start the forge viewer with the "locked orbit" option set to true by default?
Forge Viewer
Forge viewer starts always with "orbit free" option set to true.
Thank you
Alder

After the model is loaded, set NavigationLock to true.
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, async () => {
   viewer.setNavigationLock(true);
})


in case you want to reactivate navigation like pan or orbit, set NavigationLock to false and then activate the individual nav tool using toolController, ex:
viewer.setNavigationLock(false);
viewer.toolController.activateTool("pan");


Thank you @varunpatil, I finally found "NOP_VIEWER.unloadExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.FusionOrbit', null);" method to unload the fusion style orbit.
